# Powershell newline in script argument not working

Tags: string, powershell, escaping, newline, command-line-arguments

I have this little script i use to call it with differernt RegEx arguments for replacing text in files:

```
param ($file, $fnd, $rpl)

(Get-Content $file -Raw) -replace $fnd , $rpl | Set-Content $file
```

problem is if i pass it an argument containing  a new line escape code  `r`n  like so:

```
powershell -File txt-replace.ps1 "file path" "RegEx_pattern" "line1`r`nline2"
```

will write on file:

```
line1`r`nline2
```

instead of:

```
line1
line2
```

BUT IF i define $rpl inside the script, with the exact argument content, it works:

```
$rpl = "line1`r`nline2"
```

writes:

```
line1
line2
```

Also works if i run it as a command in widows terminal:

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content file_path | Out-String ).Trim() | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'RegEx_pattern' , \"line1`r`nline2\"} | Set-Content file_path "
```

i debugged it further inside the script:

```
write-host $rpl
```

writes in terminal:

```
line1`r`nline2
```

BUT

```
$rpl= "line1`r`nline2"
write-host $rpl
```

writes in terminal:

```
line1
line2
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Use `-command` instead --> `powershell -command  ".\txt-replace.ps1 \"file path\" \"RegEx_pattern\" \"line1`r`nline2\""`. Remember to backslash escape the quotes you want to pass to the script parameters because you are clearly calling from somewhere other than PowerShell.

Comment: If you are using Windows Terminal, can you retest this scenario with a PowerShell or Windows PowerShell window? It seems like you are using Command Prompt.

Comment: Thank you, using -command works, but what is the explanation?

Comment: tested in Powershell winodw and it works.
but i need to call it from a third party application trough command

Comment: With `-File` the script arguments are passed literally after interpretation by the current shell. CMD doesn't know what the newline characters are. When using `-command`, the command string is treated as if it were entered at a PowerShell prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simplest to just use `-Command` parameter.

```
powershell -Command  ".\txt-replace.ps1 \"file path\" \"RegEx_pattern\" \"line1`r`nline2\""
```

The backslash escapes are for the CMD shell. Since you want those quotes passed to PowerShell, we need to escape them first at the CMD shell layer. Otherwise, CMD will think they are surrounding strings for it to interpret.

When using `-File` the script arguments are passed literally after interpretation by the current shell. CMD doesn't know what the newline characters are so they just remain `r`n and then are passed literally as one of the string arguments.

When using `-Command`, the command string is treated as if it were entered at a PowerShell prompt.

See [About_PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) for more information.